# Where is the BIOS write protection screw in the HP Chromebook 14-db0500sa?

Tags: chromebook, google-chrome-os

I am trying to completely trash my Chromebook and install linux mint on it instead of ChromeOS. I have followed some tutorials on similar HP Chromebooks. I have removed what I think is the write-protection screw, but ChromeOS still confirms to me that write-protection is enabled.

Here is an image of my laptop under the hood, I have the removed the following screw pointed out in red. It appears to fit the description decorated with half circles? Could anybody else also confirm this? I can not find any spec of this laptop that describes it.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this model uses the write protection screw? [Post-2017 Chromebooks use a security chip](https://wiki.mrchromebox.tech/Firmware_Write_Protect#Hardware_Write_Protection).

Comment: Damn I think you're right

Comment: They haven't been that simple to bypass in years. That and all the other loopholes have all now been closed. Only the owner can release it.

Comment: A write protect screw? Never heard of that in my 30+ year career in IT. And apparantly some ChromeBooks have one. Never knew that. But that screw-hole the arrow points at looks to me like a standard mounting-screw for the motherboard (there is another visible above it on the other side of the PCB. Would make no sense whatsoever to link that to a write-protect mechanism.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes this is essentially the answer now that I know post 2017 Chromebooks do not use a WP screw anymore. I found a YouTube video which I have followed and now it works! https://youtu.be/EGZ6KfjEPP0